# How to understand this piece of code in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need help understanding this piece of code. I know the output is 10. However, I would like to know why. I am very new to Spark and I need to learn it for an academic exam. So I would like to know how it got the output.

```
data_reduce = sc.parallelize([1.0, 2, .5, .1, 5, .2], 1)
data_reduce.reduce(lambda x, y: x / y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in first line of your code we are crearting a dataframe.

```
data_reduce = sc.parallelize([1.0, 2, .5, .1, 5, .2], 1) # 1 partition
```

in above piece of code

SC : sc is the spark context variable we are using here. As you are executing the spark shell so spark shell autmatically provides you the sc variable. but in case of other non spark shell applications you will have to create another sc variable.
sc is like entry point of you program. SparkContext is created you can use it to create RDDs, accumulators and broadcast variables, access Spark services and run jobs

parallelize : There are multiple ways to create rdd in spark. Example loading a file, loading data from table similarly using parallelize functions you can create dataframe by passing collections like arrays and list see the example below

```
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
```

data_reduce : This is your RDD onceOnce created, the distributed dataset (data_reduce) can be operated on in parallel.

**second line of code**

```
data_reduce.reduce(lambda x, y: x / y)
```

Here we are calling reduce function in your RDD. In your example here we are doing cumulative sum of all the elements in your RDD. I hope you are aware of partitions concepts in RDD. Then we know our data is distributed across different nodes in form of partitions in you case

```
[1.0, 2, .5, .1, 5, .2]
```

lets say if it is distributed in two partitions

so it will be like

partition 1 : [1.0, 2, .5]
partition 2 : [.1, 5, .2]

Now here reduce function will be called on each partitions

Here reduce method accepts a `function (accum, n) => (accum + n)`. This function initialize accumulator(accum) variable with default integer value 0, divides up an element every when reduce method is called and returns final value when all elements of RDD X are processed. It returns the final value rather than another RDD.

okay so lets understand how reduce is working here

- step 1 : [1.0, 2, .5, .1, 5, .2].reduce(lambda x,y : x/y )
          here x = 1.0 , y=2  thus x/y = 0.5
- step 2:  now 0.5 will be stored in x and y will be new element from
  rdd
             so x= 0.5 and y = 0.5 thus x/y = 1
- step 3 : Similarly now x = 1 and y = 0.1 so x/y = 10
- step 4 : x=10,y=5 so x/y = 2
- step 5 : x=2, y=0.2 so x/y = 10

So 10 is your final answer i hope i clears you now :)

You can read more detailed info about reduce function from [here](https://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-reduce-example/)